# Cardinality of the class of Topologies

Tags: general-topology

How to show that on an infinite set $X$, uncountably many topologies can be defined.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: For any $A\subseteq X$, the family $\{\varnothing,A,X\}$ is a topology on $X$.

Comment: Since $X$ is infinite, the set of all of its subsets is uncountable and so the family of all topologies on $X$ is uncountable. Is it? @ B M Scott

Comment: @SucharitaDeb: That’s right.